# Converting from a date range to month range

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I want to convert the below from a set date range to a whole month range:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(Advisors) AS TotalNumber FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded WHERE Advisors = '" & Forms!frm_Central_Reporting_ops!Label44.Caption & "' AND [Mail Date] between #01/04/2016# AND #30/04/2016#")
```

I have tried:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(Advisors) AS TotalNumber FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded WHERE Advisors = '" & Forms!frm_Central_Reporting_ops!Label44.Caption & "' AND month[Mail Date] ='April'")
```

Also tried:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(Advisors) AS TotalNumber FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded WHERE Advisors = '" & Forms!frm_Central_Reporting_ops!Label44.Caption & "' AND month[Mail Date] ='4'")
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: `month([Mail Date]) = 4` finds April, note that you need a `year()` as well unless you want all Aprils.

Comment: Google the Access DatePart() command. You will probably what to make sure you only pull a specific year  and month not just every date in April for ever.
https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datepart.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in earlier comments, you'll likely want to reference a year as well, otherwise all 'April' items will be included, regardless of year.

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(Advisors) AS TotalNumber FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded WHERE Advisors = '" & Forms!frm_Central_Reporting_ops!Label44.Caption & "' AND month([Mail Date]) =4")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The code works. I am trying to add the year in but with no success, can you spot my mistake: Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(Advisors) AS TotalNumber FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded WHERE Advisors = '" & Forms!frm_Central_Reporting_ops!Label44.Caption & "' AND year([2016]) AND month([Mail Date]) =4")

Comment: Is is possible to get the YEAR to look at a textbox for a value. Im trying to use: AND year(me.text46) AND month([Mail Date]) =4")

Comment: Assuming the form you want to reference is open, you can do something like: 

`Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(Advisors) AS TotalNumber FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded WHERE Advisors = '" & Forms!frm_Central_Reporting_ops!Label44.Caption & "' AND month([Mail Date]) =4 and year([mail date])=forms!formname!textboxname") `where you'll need to reference the form name (formname)' and textbox that contains the date you want to grab the year of.  If the text box itself is just a year, you don't need the year() wrapper.